# Jeet framework: How to make Jeet sticky-menu continue when reaching footerlevel?

Tags: css-frameworks

Is there a way to make the Jeet relatively-sticky menu https://github.com/CorySimmons/relatively-sticky continue upwards when it reach the top level of the footer-section?

In my case the footer-section streches horizontaly over the whole page.

Comment: Cory Simmons here. Could you provide an example or something? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Sorry :(

Comment: Like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/k56yR/1/

Comment: You'd probably have to set it to something other than position: relative which would defeat the point. :[